# Ubuntu Server 12.04 Apache httpd 2.2.22 mod_rewrite not working

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

I am trying to set up a distributed web farm using apache2. Before deploying the configuration to my other 3 servers, I wanted to get everything to work on the first one (designated P-WEB-01) at 10.0.2.1. I have multiple sites set up through virtual hosts, and the different domain names are all working properly.

However, my problem is with apache_mod_rewrite, where I'm attempting to set up a url that looks like this : http://example.com/firstvariable/secondvariable/thirdvaraible and have it read by the PHP script (index.php) as http://example.com/index.pp?a=firstvariable&b=secondvariable&c=thirdvariable. The system also has to be set up in a way where the mod_rewrite ignores internal file names and directories, as they are proxied to the external site (for security purposes) through the script.

I had this script running on an IIS7 server for a while, and it worked perfectly fine. Also, I have followed the whole a2enmod mod_rewrite, which outputted success. I enabled AllowOverride All in apache2.conf, and set up the sites .htaccess file in the site's root directory, and had it say:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.html
```

which still did nothing.

Comment: I've restarted apache, as well as the entire server

Comment: You have to write more sophisticated re-write. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite

Comment: RewriteRule ^example.com/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ example.com/index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=3[NC] assuming your php script will validate the input and handle empty variables ;)

Comment: The problem is not the rewrite script, although I will for sure use some direvation of the script written in the last comment. My problem is that, for some reason, mod_rewrite will not even activate. I tried a simple script: ^index.php$ index.html and it would output "404 index.html not found"

Comment: Nothing is matching ^index.php . Your example url is " http://example.com/firstvariable/secondvariable/thirdvaraible" . Nothing in your example url matches "index.php" , let alone ^index.php . I suggest you either read up on regular expressions or post the actual url you want us to debug. Otherwise I would say fix $your_expression

Comment: The example.com/firstvariable/secondvariable/thirdvaraible is what I'd like to have in the long run, however I am saying that the mod_rewrite will now even initiate. For example, with the .htaccess file reading: "RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.html", going to example.com/index.html should internally pull index.php and rewrite the url to index.html, but instead outputs 404.

Comment: "example.com/index.html" does not match "^index.php$" , and I assume you have no index.html, thus a 404 "Not found" error.

Comment: Ok, so first off, thank your for your patience. Your help is important to me. Now, I tried to implement your configuration, and did so by adding it to the sites .htaccess file in the root directory. It looked like this: 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^example.com/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ example.com/index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=3[NC]
Still, when visiting any page, I get a 404 error unless it's the index.php file I'm trying to use for everything. I believe that mod_rewrite is not enabled, and I've tried everything to activate it.

Comment: I can see other people using apache2 on ubuntu server 12.04 have had similiar problems.

Comment: I do not know what "similar problems" means and I think your issues is that you have not written a good rewrite rule. I gave you a link that reviews the basics. If it is not working, post additional information. Try `RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php` Make sure you have an index.php (example/index.php should work). Then go to example/index.html . See also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: To make this more understandable, I will show you the basic layout of the PHP scripts. This script goes like:
<?php
if(!$_GET['a']){
    //assume its home
    echo 'home';
}elseif($_GET['a'] == 'search'){
    //show search
    echo 'search';
}else{
    //for dynamic pages
    if($pgeexistsindatabase == true){
        echo "page";
    }else{
        //page not found.
        echo '404';
    }
}
Now, using your rewrite rule seems right, so I went ahead and implemented it. However, it failed. I then tried using the index.php to index.html rewrite rule as a test for it, and it too did not work.

Comment: see if this helps (I am not sure). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272328/mod-rewrite-not-working-on-ubuntu-server-works-locally-though . did you enable mod rewrite and restart apache ?

Comment: I've already done sudo a2enmod rewrite (which indicates it's enabled), as well as changing AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All. I think something might be wrong server side...

Comment: bodi.zazen can you please post your solution to the answers so I can +1 it please? :)

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: It wasn't just this, but I didn't make the rewrite rule properly, also the virtual host file was configuring weird from Webmin...

Comment: Glad you got it sorted , you can post the solution that worked for you, otherwise have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w.]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([\w.]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/([\w.]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L,QSA]
```

As well as made sure my firewall (IPTables-based) was actually forwarding to the correct (new) webserver.

Thanks everyone! :)